# Add fields and query manually to existing single group layout

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, oraclereports

I already have a group called G_1 in my report and the entire fieldset required for the report are present in G_1.
Now, I have a new requirement which needs data from different tables and hence I created a new query using "Data wizard" and a group called G_2 was created as well.
I don't want to affect the layout of the existing report(every field is in a single repeat frame) and wanted to add my new fields as well  
I added fields and mapped the data, but then I got error saying **"field references column below its group frequency"** 
So I have to bring the column under the existing group G_1 without using report wizard.

Any leads would be of big help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are saying, that won't work.

If you created a new query, it has its group (G_2) and fields selected within that query have to belong to G_2 group. In Paper Layout, by default, every query has the outer frame (M_2), it contains a repeating frame (R_2) and fields have to be part of those frames.

If you set flex off and confine off (so that you could drag fields here and there, even out of its boundaries (frames) and actually do that - drag a field to, say, R_1 frame (which is part of M_1 which belongs to query 1), you'll get that error.

So, what to do?

If possible, the simplest option would be to adjust query Q_1 and add those new fields in there. If not, you'll have those two queries.

One option is to put query 2 objects (frames, fields) below the ones that belong to query 1 (so that they are unrelated). Another is to stretch query 1 frames "down" and make space for query 2 objects. Then you'd draw a M_2 frame (paint it white so that you can easily see what's going on). Within M_2, draw a repeating frame R_2 and paint it yellow. It has to be contained in M_2. Now, create the first field within the R_2 repeating frame. Check the Object Navigator - everything has to be in its place. If it is not, you'll have to move objects backwards (or forward).

Run the report - if it works OK, fine - go on to the next field, and so forth. Test frequently. Once you're done, make it prettier - move everything to its right place, remove painting and - that's it.

---

On the other hand: as there's only one frame you currently have (I don't know how many fields there are and how complex the layout is), if you are an unexperienced Reports user, your best option is to delete current layout and let the **Wizard** do the job. It'll certainly ruin everything you've done so far, but it has its advantages - all objects will be on their proper places. Might be time consuming, but adjusting fields and headings and stuff could be simpler and easier.

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do it. Takes time to gain experience, but - if you have it - go for it. How will you learn how to do it if you actually don't do it?

Best of luck!